# Unable to find a source package for linux-image-unsigned-4.9.140-tegra

Tags: 18.04, kernel

Trying to patch a driver on my Jetson Nano, I first need to get the kernel source. However, running `apt-get source linux-image-unsigned-$(uname -r)` gives me the following error:

> Unable to find a source package for linux-image-unsigned-4.9.140-tegra

Please advise.

Comment: I'm trying the very same thing. Namely patching UVC driver to support more than 2 USB cameras. Did you happen to find a solution? I'd be very interested!

Comment: Hi, I didn't yet, but it was on the backburner and I'm about to start digging myself in earnest. Will let you know if anything comes up.

Comment: Realize that this topic is old by now, but the solution is to use the link https://developer.nvidia.com/embedded/linux-tegra after logging in with an Nvidia developer account. Hope this helps.